# 502 Bad Gateway when using ExpressJS with nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket, express, nowjs-sockets

If I run my expressjs app like so: `coffee server.coffee` and navigate to `localhost:8080`, everything works just fine.

However, when I reverse proxy 8080 with nginx with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nodetest.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://node/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

upstream node {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

I get the following error in the Chrome Dev console:

`GET http://184.73.217.204/socket.io/xhr-polling//1300750540040 502 (Bad Gateway)`

and the following in nginx's `error.log`

```
2011/03/22 13:07:59 [error] 10269#0: *18 upstream prematurely closed connection while
reading response header from upstream, client: 168.229.58.68, server: localhost, 
request:     "GET /socket.io/xhr-polling//1300799281533 HTTP/1.1", upstream:     
"http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/xhr-polling/1300799281533", host: "184.73.217.204",    
referrer: "http://184.73.217.204/"
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: What do you see in <code>error_log</code>?

Comment: 2011/03/22 13:07:59 [error] 10269#0: *18 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 168.229.58.68, server: localhost, request: "GET /socket.io/xhr-polling//1300799281533 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/xhr-polling/1300799281533", host: "184.73.217.204", referrer: "http://184.73.217.204/"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this patch...

```
    -proxy_pass http://node/;
    +proxy_pass http://node;
```

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass -- here is documentation

If it is necessary to transmit URI in the unprocessed form then directive proxy_pass should be used without URI part:

location  /some/path/ {
  proxy_pass   _http://127.0.0.1;
}

Comment: wow hours of debugging and it's a freaking slash that threw off my entire app. upvoted!

Comment: Genius!!!! I just want to say thanks, this took me hours and hours and hours of debugging!

Comment: I tried this but it just doesn't seem to work. Any words of wisdom? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256454/websocket-connection-invalid-when-using-nginx-on-node-js-server/9256492#9256492

Answer (score 2):

I am new to setting up a VMS using `nginx` and `forever` with `nodejs`/`meanjs`. My goal was to configure a proxy to be able to serve my app on the default port 80 rather than from port 3000.

While fumbling about with nginx server block snippets from a variety of different online examples I started to hit a wall with "502 Bad Gateway" errors. Through a lot of trial and error I was finally able to resolve this condition.

In the end, what seemed like equivalent ways of using `forever` to start `node` ended up with very different results.

#### What results in 502 Bad Gateway:

When issued from the server's root using an absolute path to the node script, this command failed with a 502:

```
$ cd /
$ sudo forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 /var/www/mydomain.com/server.js
```

Actually, for that matter if `node` is not running at all I was also getting a 502 error.

#### What works:

Two ways that did work were either starting `forever` from my project's root directory without specifying a path to the node script (just the filename) or again from the server's root but using the `sourceDir` option:

```
$ cd /var/www/mydomain.com
$ sudo forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 server.js
```

Or:

```
$ cd /
$ sudo forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 --sourceDir /var/www/shotplot.info/ server.js
```

Just for completeness I will also include the nginx server block in case that helps provide some additional context:

```
upstream nodejs \{
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
server {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://nodejs;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```