# "websocket connection invalid" when using nginx on node.js server

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm using Express.js to create a server to which I can connect using web sockets.

Even though it eventually seems to work (that, is connects and passes an event to the client), I initially get an error in Chrome's console:

> Unexpected response code: 502

On the backend, the socket.io only logs `warn  - websocket connection invalid`.

However, nginx logs this:

> 2012/02/12 23:30:03 [error] 25061#0: *81 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   71.122.117.15, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /socket.io/1/websocket/1378920683898138448 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8090/socket.io/1/websocket/1378920683898138448",
>   host: "www.example.com"

Note: I have nginx dev running: `nginx version: nginx/1.1.14` so it should support HTTP/1.1.

Also note that if I just use the node.js server without the nginx it works without any warnings.

Finally, here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_pass http://node;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }
}

upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:8090;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried the fix suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385036/502-bad-gateway-when-using-expressjs-with-nginx) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx has some kind of Web Socket support in unstable 1.1 branch only. See Socket.IO [wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Nginx-and-Socket.io).

Afaik there are currently only few stable Node.js based http proxies that support Web Sockets properly.

Check out node-http-proxy (we use this):

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

and bouncy:

https://github.com/substack/bouncy

Or you can use pure TCP proxy such as [HAproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)

### Update!

nginx (1.3.13>=) supports websockets out of the box!

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: I thought it was supported in the dev branch?!

Comment: I ended up using `bouncy` as you suggested, @Epeli. nginx 1.1.14, much like 1.1.4 doesn't seem to work as noted here:  
  
NOTE: At time of writing (v1.1.4), Nginx 1.1 still can't support web sockets.

Comment: I received similar error in NGINX@1.1.16.. It's working but it's very slow, which probably means that it's using a different transport mechanism.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with NGINX 1.2.3 which is supposed to work. Anyone?

Comment: I think 1.3.13 is the first version of nginx to support websockets