# Use Django+Redis+Socket.io to build chat room, where to start?

Tags: django, socket.io

I've heard of these three giant technologies would allow developers to build pub/sub paradigm which result in rapid server push experience.

I've got background on Django, but non of the other two. So just wondering, where can I kick off?

I currently use Gunicorn as django server, uses Nginx as a proxy to serve static files, uses Haproxy as a front-end load balancer. After I adopt new technology stack, can I keep them still?

Comment: I think you should check out - http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/

and this earlier question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190186/can-i-use-socket-io-with-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here:

- http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org

and here:

- https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio

There are some Django examples as to how to get started.  Your tech. stack should allow you to run this without much problems.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably encounter issues using Socket.io (which will try to use websocket) with Nginx. Nginx 1.0 does not support proxying of HTTP/1.1. You can use tcp_proxy to work around it. You might be able to find some forks for Nginx 1.1 that have websocket support though.

Check out [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Nginx-and-Socket.io) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256454/websocket-connection-invalid-when-using-nginx-on-node-js-server).